# Substance Painter/Blender Height Issue

Tags: height-map

The first image is a Substance Painter Iray render. This is how I would like it to look.
The next image is the render from Blender (2.91) - the next is the node setup. The render results are identical between Cycles and Eevee. Obviously there is a large difference in bump strength between SP and Blender. I have removed the bump connection and it's back to normal - so appears to be isolated to bump only, and not a normal issue.
My mesh is set to real life dimensions (about 20") and the unit set up is Imperial/inches.
So I can set the distance, on the bump map node, to correct the height issue - but I have to really crank it down - like .001. This makes me think maybe I'm doing something wrong - doesn't seem like there should be that large of a discrepancy between the 2 renderers??? But maybe so.
Anyone else notice this? Any ideas or suggestions to get the Blender/SP height difference sorted out - or is it just the way it is?
Thanks

[image: Substance Painter Iray Render]

[image: Blender Render (Cycles and Eevee]

[image: Blender Nodees]

[image: Substance Painter Exports]

Comment: I think the distance is in blender units (meters) meaning a value of 1 (white) in the height map would theoretically give a displacement of 1 meter. There is no actual displacement though so your mesh just looks like a ball of foiled aluminium. Depending on the scale of your object, a displacement of 0.001 (1 mm) would make sense then to achieve the look in your 1st image

Comment: Thanks. I think you are correct but I find it curious that Blender continues to use its own units even though I have set a different scale. Are the scene units different than those used by the node system I wonder? And another question would be where Substance Painter gets its unit/scale system.

Comment: As far as I know the scale in the scene settings is just a visual tweak for user interface, under the hood it still treats units as blender units.